# Quick calculation for $x^y \bmod 2^d$

Tags: arithmetic, number-theory, integers

I need to calculate $x^y \bmod 2^d$ in $O(d)$ summations/bitwise operations and $1$ multiplication by $y$. $x$ is restricted to be odd, $d\geq 3$.

$a$-bit arithmetic *(for any $a$)* is allowed, as this is just a theoretical question.